# Delphi 7 - TMS Intraweb DB-aware Grid

Tags: javascript, delphi, intraweb, tms, data-aware

I'm making a web application by using Delphi 7 and TMS suite for Intraweb. I have several client dataset components and I use a TTIWDBAdvWebGrid for showing the data. TTIWDBAdvWebGrid is a data-aware component, but when I modify some values in grid, the data is not persistent(on cell events the value of the cell is the old one, not the value set by me).

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the event is not triggered well.also, the OnDirectEditUpdate event does not occur.
the following code(put in ClientEvents->EditDone) is solving the problem:

```
if (IsEditing(obj))
{
valedt =GetEditValue(IWDBECRITCOUPLESObj,c,r);
i = GetEditRow(IWDBECRITCOUPLESObj);
SetEditValue(IWDBECRITCOUPLESObj,8,i,valedt);
}
```

after this, the value is set on the dataset.

IWDBECRITCOUPLES is the name of the grid component on the form. 
GetEditValue and SetEditValue have the parameters gridname(followed by Obj suffix), column, row and Value(only SetEditValue function)
GetEditRow has the parameter gridname(followed by Obj)

Comment: because nobody answer to my question, I'll accept my own answer.